# Terminal shows wrong version of Python after fresh installation on M1 Mac

Tags: macos, python-3.8, apple-m1, python-3.9

I downloaded Python 3.9.7 universal2 installer and installed Python on my M1-chip MacBook. Note that this was the first Python installation on this machine except for Apple-provided Python 2.7.16.

Then after running `python3 --version` line in the Terminal I've got this output `xcode-select: note: no developer tools were found at '/Applications/Xcode.app', requesting install. Choose an option in the dialog to download the command line developer tools.` and a pop-up window was opened suggesting installing necessary software. I installed it.

After that I ran `python3 --version` line again and got this output: `Python 3.8.2`. The expected output is `Python 3.9.7`.

What happened? Did I do anything wrong? How to fix it?

Answer (score -1):

It turns out that at least for M1 Macs Apple provides two versions of Python: **2.7.16** and **3.8.2** by default. The commands `python --version` and `python3 --version` correspond to them as they appear. The command needed to be used is `python3.9 --version` which outputs `Python 3.9.7` as expected.